# Accessing data within cloud function Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to access data from firebase cloud function.

I have group of users (like a group chat) and each group has  key.

I try to access the group within a cloud function :

```
admin.database().ref('/GroupUsers/${groupKey}').once('value');
```

and get the following error:

> ```
>           Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "/GroupUsers/${groupKey}". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
> at Error (native)
> at qd (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:97:59)
> at W.h.n (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:257:178)
> at ch.h.gf (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:218:663)
> at exports.startContest.functions.database.ref.onUpdate.event (/user_code/index.js:21:49)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
> at next (native)
> at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
> at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
> at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
> ```

where group key is input to onUpdate Firebase' cloud function

Thank u in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert a variable inside a string in JavaScript, use backticks to delimit the string (you're using single quotes).

```
admin.database().ref(`/GroupUsers/${groupKey}`).once('value');
```

Comment: I want to read a data. I tried what you suggested Now I get the following:   "ReferenceError: groupKey is not defined"